# Disable entire month in vaadin date picker

Tags: javascript, vaadin, web-component, polymer-2.x

I am trying to disable all dates of all months in vaadin-date-picker. While looking through the code,
I found that I can individually disable dates by setting `disabled` in   [vaadin-month-calendar.html#L75](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-date-picker/blob/master/src/vaadin-month-calendar.html#L75) . In that case the disabled date is faded, which is due to [vaadin-month-calendar-styles.html#L119](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-date-picker/blob/master/theme/lumo/vaadin-month-calendar-styles.html#L119), and one can not select the disabled date any more.

Similarly, I have done the following,

```
<div id="days" part="days" disabled>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[_days]]">
        <div part="date" today$="[[_isToday(item)]]" selected$="[[_dateEquals(item, selectedDate)]]" focused$="[[_dateEquals(item, focusedDate)]]" date="[[item]]" disabled$="[[!_dateAllowed(item, minDate, maxDate)]]" role$="[[_getRole(item)]]" aria-label$="[[_getAriaLabel(item)]]" aria-disabled$="[[_getAriaDisabled(item, minDate, maxDate)]]">[[_getDate(item)]]</div>
    </template>
</div>
```

And added the required style:

```
[part="days"][disabled] {
    color: var(--lumo-disabled-text-color);
}
```

In this case, all dates of all months are faded, but the user stiil can select them. Am I missing something? How to make disabled dates not selectable as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found it, just need to add `pointer-events: none;`